# ActiveRecord relationship practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have below models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, headline
end
```

~

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :bar
  has_many :sites
  has_many :articles, :through => :sites
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

~

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :article_id
  belongs_to :unit
  belongs_to :article
end
```

~

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  has_many :sites
  has_many :units, :through => :sites
end
```

Now on `foos_controller` I get foo's units:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  #...
  units = Unit.where(:foo_id => params[:foo_id])
  # Now here I want to set each unit title with its site.article.title
end
```

how can I set the `unit.title` with its `site.article.title`?

Comment: Does a `Unit` have one or many `Site`s?  That association seems to be missing...

Comment: @PinnyM: You are right, I just updated the post.

Comment: If it has many sites - which of the associated sites do you want to use to determine the title? Any of them?

Comment: we can get the first site article title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it appears that a `Unit` has one `Site` - so you need to add that association:

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :foo
  has_one :site
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
units = Unit.where(:foo_id => params[:foo_id]).includes(:articles)
units.each do |unit| 
   unit.update_attributes(title: unit.articles.first.title)
end
```

Note the use of `includes` in the original query.  This will eager load the articles necessary to avoid an N+1 query problem when you iterate through the units.

Note that this approach assumes you don't have very many articles per unit.  If you did, this would need to be tweaked to avoid loading too many articles unnecessarily.

Comment: on the query if I include `:sites`, then I could also have something like: `unit.update_attributes(title: unit.sites.first.article.title)` right?

Comment: Actually, once you include articles, it includes sites for free. If you only include sites, you'll still have the N+1 issue when getting the article.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Site should also `belongs_to :article` based on the syntax you're using and based on the fact that it has an article_id. You can remove `attr_accessible :article_id` unless you explicitly want that to change and instead add `belongs_to :article`. You'll then be able to call `unit.title = site.article.title` (or you could use `unit.update_attribute('title',site.article.title)`

Comment: Add `has_many :sites` to the User class. Then you can call `unit.title = unit.sites.where([your query]).first.article.title`

Comment: OK, now it's slightly easier since Unit has many articles. Call `unit.title = unit.articles.where([your query]).first.title`